# Mysql insert query failed

Tags: mysql, linux, perl

Hello i am trying to insert some data into mysql using perl.
i have an array that i want insert into a table. but problem is that the array has a " ' "
.when i try to insert it got an error mysql query failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
@abc = "FUJI-XEROX CO. LTD. ADVANCED TECH & ENG'G CENTER 9-50 CHUO 2-CHOME, EBINA-SHI KANAGAWA 24 JAPAN";



$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:remotegenius;host=localhost', 'root', 'active123') or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
$dbh->do("insert into OUI set `oui`='$abc'");
```

when i execute code i got

```
DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'G CENTER 9-50 CHUO 2-CHOME, EBINA-SHI KANAGAWA 24 JAPAN'' at line 1 at ./test.pl line 9.
```

I need someone help from mysql and perl expertise.

Comment: You need to escape the string (i.e., the ```'``` in the string $abc). Or use prepared statements (which is even better!)

Comment: i know that but how would i escape it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it is *essential* to `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* program. It saves a huge amount of time by revealing simple mistakes, and would have alerted you to the fact that you put a string into array `@abc` and then use the scalar `$abc` in your SQL statement. I assume here that you intended to use `$abc` throughout.

Your error is because that's not what an `INSERT` statement looks like. You also need to escape and quote the string in `$abc` properly as it contains single quotes, so you must write

```
$dbh->do(sprintf 'INSERT INTO oui (oui) VALUES (%s)', $dbh->quote($abc))
```

But it is best to *prepare* the statement first and then execute it

```
my $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO oui (oui) VALUES (?)');
```

and later

```
$insert->execute($abc);
```

---

Or perhaps you mean `"UPDATE oui SET oui = ?"`? But that will set the `oui` field to the same value on every row of the table.

Comment: The case of the vanishing downvote! I don't think I'm wrong am I?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you need to escape special characters with the [`quote`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#quote) method if you don't use placeholders (your first snippet). Also, where's your usual admonishment about strict and warnings? I'm sure it gets tiring to type the same thing over and over, but the new users will thank you :)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yeah well I assumed that the OP knew whether the contents of `$abc` needed escaping, but that was clearly unwise as I have just noticed that `$abc` is meant to be the `@abc` that they set before the insert. I also hadn't spotted that the original code contained a shebang line, and assumed it was a code fragment. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @user2916639: What is your table name? If it is `OUI` instead of `oui` then change the statement to `INSERT INTO OUI (oui) VALUES (?)`

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work with either `oui` or `OUI`? Is `remotegenius` the right database? I can't really tell what's wrong without knowing more about your batabase, so I suggest you open a new question.

Comment: @user2916639: You should take a look at the database. List the tables with `mysqlshow remotegenius` on the command line, and see if `mysqlshow remotegenius OUI` works.

Comment: Can you explain the solution please @user2916639? The hope is that this page will help many more people than yourself, and the extra information about what you did to fix it may make all the difference to somebody.

Comment: @Borodin did you give minus to this question...? anyways when i tried   solution that you have given , i was getting error table doesn't exist that was my mistake, when i corrected it. it was working fine . i used $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO oui (oui) VALUES (?)'); $insert->execute($abc);. i want to know one more this, if i want to insert multiple fields then how would do by this code.

Comment: @user2916639: No downvote from me, but I think your question was very poor. How come the code that you say works is *identical* to my solution that you said was faulty?

Comment: yes question could be poor for expertise . but i am just a beginner. your code was not faulty that was my mistake . actually i have create table inside another db. so it was saying . Table doesn't exist. Extremely sorry for that reply . just correcting it .

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert array of values, first make sure you have values in array variable.

```
@vals = ('One', 'Two', 'Three');
```

Error is because INSERT query syntax is wrong, here is the INSERT syntax

```
INSERT INTO <table> (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2)
```

Here is the snippet that should work for you

```
use DBI;
my @vals = ('One', 'Two', 'Three');
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:remotegenius;host=localhost', 'root', 'active123') or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $in = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO oui (oui) VALUES (?)');
foreach (@vals) {
  $in->execute($_);
}
```

`

Comment: @user2916639: Please don't write like that to someone who is trying to help you.